# Spectra of $\{A_k\}_{k=1}^\infty \cup \{A_\infty\}$ and Continuity of the Spectrum

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory

> Consider the family of operators $\mathcal F$ on $\mathcal H = \ell^2(\Bbb Z)$ given by $\mathcal F = \{A_k\}_{k=1}^\infty \cup \{A_\infty\}$ where
> $$A_k e_n = \begin{cases}e_{n+1} & n \ne 0\\ \frac{e_{n+1}}{k} & n = 0 \end{cases}$$
> and $1/\infty := 0$. What are the spectra of operators in $\mathcal F$? Is the spectrum "continuous"?

I presume this amounts to finding $\sigma(A_k)$ for $k\in \Bbb N$, and $\sigma(A_\infty)$ separately, and taking the limit (in some sense) as $k\to\infty$ to see that the spectrum (as a map from $\mathcal B(\mathcal H)$ to compact subsets of $\Bbb C$ is not continuous.) For $x = \sum_n x_n e_n \in \mathcal H$ and $\lambda \in \Bbb C$, we have
$$(A_k - \lambda I) x = \left(\frac{x_0}{k} - x_1\lambda\right)e_1 + \sum_{n\ne 0} (x_n - \lambda x_{n+1})e_{n+1}$$
and
$$(A_\infty - \lambda I) x =  -x_1\lambda e_1 + \sum_{n\ne 0} (x_n - \lambda x_{n+1})e_{n+1}$$
How should I proceed? I do not have a guess for the spectra of operators in $\mathcal F$. Thank you!

Comment: The operator $A_k$ is a one dimensional perturbation of the shift operator. Therefore $\{|z|=1\}\subset \sigma(A_k).$

Comment: See whe $(A_k-\lambda I)x=y$ has  a unique solution and when $y \to x$ is continuous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $S$ denote the shift operator defined as $Se_n=e_{n+1}.$ Let $M_k$ be the operator defined by
$$M_ke_n=\begin{cases} e_n & n\ge 1\\
ke_n & n\le 0
\end{cases}
$$
Then $A_k=M_kSM_k^{-1}.$ Therefore $\sigma(A_k)=\sigma(S).$ It is well known that $\sigma(S)=\{z\,:\,|z|=1\}.$ Hence $\sigma(A_k)=\{z\,:\,|z|=1\}$ for $k\in \mathbb{N}.$

For the operator $A_\infty$ we have the orthogonal decomposition $\ell^2(\mathbb{Z})=\ell^2(\mathbb{N})\oplus\ell^2(-\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}),$ where both subspaces are invariant for the operator $A_\infty.$ Therefore $\sigma(A_\infty)$ is equal to the union of the spectra of $A_\infty$ restricted to each of the subspaces. The operator $A_\infty$ restricted to the first subspace is the unilateral shift whose spectrum coincides with $\{z\,:\,|z|\le 1\}.$ Similarly the operator $A_\infty$ restricted to the second subspace is the adjoint of the unilateral shift, hence its spectrum also coincides with $\{z\,:\,|z|\le 1\}.$ Summarizing $\sigma(A_\infty)=\{z\,:\,|z|\le 1\}.$

Comment: How does the fact that $A_k$ is a one-dimensional perturbation (whatever that means) help you deduce that the unit circle is in the spectrum of $A_k$? I haven't seen this before.

Comment: If $A=B+K,$ where $K$ is a compact operator then accumulation points of the sets $\sigma(A)$ and  $\sigma(B)$ are equal.  In other words the continuous spectra are the same. [See](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://math.ou.edu/~cremling/teaching/lecturenotes/fa-new/ln15.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjuw7fgt5__AhULv4sKHXrqB4gQFnoECAoQAQ&usg=AOvVaw3ABIHhKI7hTDONal2aHbKr)

Comment: I have re-edited the answer to avoid applying the perturbation theory in this particular case.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc:  When $|\lambda|=1$, $(\lambda I-S)^{-1}T_k$ is not defined because $\operatorname{Range}(T_k)=\operatorname{span}(e_1)$ and $e_1\not\in\operatorname{Range}(\lambda I-S)$.

Comment: @JohnDoe Thanks. You are right.  I was too careless. I will remove the remark

Comment: My first answer was totally wrong as the perturbation theorem is valid for self-adjoint operators. I have thoroughly revised the answer, hopefully in a correct way.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc: $A_\infty\rvert_{\ell^2(-\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\})}$ has the obvious kernel $\operatorname{span}(e_0)$, so its spectrum (and that of $A_\infty$) is $\Bbb{T}\cup \{0\}$ as the original answer said.

Comment: @JohnDoe The adjoint of the unilateral shift has one dimensional kernel. Moreover every number $|\lambda|<1$ is its eigenvalue. The spectrum coincides with the closed unit disc. The original answer was wrong.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc: Oh, right - the decreasing exponential sequence $\lambda^n$ (going left) is also an eigenvector.